# Why is my XPath ignoring a predicate and selecting multiple nodes?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

```
<flow-end-node _nghost-c50="" id="T000k2d27hnb" class="jtk-draggable jtk-droppable ng-star-inserted jtk-endpoint-anchor jtk-connected xh-highlight" style="top: 160px; left: 592px; z-index: 102;">
<div _ngcontent-c50="" class="invisible-node-holder node-setup">
  <div _ngcontent-c50="" class="node-anchor left target"></div>
  <button _ngcontent-c50="" class="mat-fab" mat-fab="" style="background: rgb(66, 189, 65);"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
    <mat-icon _ngcontent-c50="" class="mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">done</mat-icon>
    <flow-notification-icon _ngcontent-c50="" _nghost-c48="">

<!---->
</flow-notification-icon>
  </span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
  <label _ngcontent-c50="">End (success)</label>
</div></flow-end-node>

<flow-end-node _nghost-c50="" id="T000k2d27hnc" class="jtk-draggable jtk-droppable ng-star-inserted jtk-endpoint-anchor jtk-connected xh-highlight" style="top: 368px; left: 816px; z-index: 103;">

<div _ngcontent-c50="" class="invisible-node-holder node-setup">
  <div _ngcontent-c50="" class="node-anchor left target"></div>
  <button _ngcontent-c50="" class="mat-fab" mat-fab="" style="background: rgb(230, 42, 16);"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
    <mat-icon _ngcontent-c50="" class="mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">clear</mat-icon>
    <flow-notification-icon _ngcontent-c50="" _nghost-c48="">

<!---->

</flow-notification-icon>
  </span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
  <label _ngcontent-c50="">End (failure)</label>
</div></flow-end-node>
```

Have the above elements in the webpage, I would like to fetch the flow-end-node which has the label with text 'End (success)'. I have tried the below two approaches and **would like to understand why the first one is not working**.

1. `//flow-end-node[//label[text()='End (success)']]` ( this one giving me two nodes)
2. `//label[text()='End (success)']/ancestor::flow-end-node` ( this is working fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first XPath is selecting two nodes because there are two `flow-end-nodes` in your document.  Your predicate merely checks for the presence of a `label` ***anywhere in the document***, not as a descendent of `flow-end-node`.

To correct, change from absolute `//label`,

```
//flow-end-node[//label[text()='End (success)']]
```

to relative `.//label`,

```
//flow-end-node[.//label[text()='End (success)']]
```

and then only one `flow-end-node` will be selected, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

or

```
//flow-end-node[descendant::label[. = 'End (success)']]
```